# nHibernate returns zero records from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, nhibernate, resultset

I have to execute a stored procedure in SQL that returns a few rows, but I can never seem to capture the results in nHibernate.  I've asked my whole Dev team to no avail.  Here's my code:

```
        var results = this.Session.CreateSQLQuery("EXEC qa.AdjustDates @VpGuarantorId =:VpGuarantorId, @DatePart =:DatePart, @Adjustment =:Adjustment")
            .AddScalar("IssueLevel", NHibernateUtil.String)
            .AddScalar("IssueMessage", NHibernateUtil.String)
            .SetParameter("VpGuarantorId", guarantorId)
            .SetParameter("DatePart", datePart)
            .SetParameter("Adjustment", adjustment)
            .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof (IssueResult)))
            .List<IssueResult>()
            .ToList();
```

Here's the class:

```
public class IssueResult
{
    public virtual string IssueLevel { get; set; }
    public virtual string IssueMessage { get; set; }
}
```

(P.S. - SQL Profiler shows our app is correctly calling the proc and passing the right parameters)

Comment: Try it without the result transformer?... just use `List()` and see what you get

Comment: No error reported, just zero records always coming back in nHibernate.

Comment: @dotjoe - I did try it with just a List(), nothing.  Been at this for 8 hours!

Comment: try removing the AddScalars?

Comment: Maybe too obvious but did you try run the query with these parameter values and were there results in sql?

Comment: @Hace - Yes, that was the first thing I did.  Good suggestion, though.

Comment: @dotjoe - So, my code began without scalars originally.  I added them in out of desperation.  Either way, no dice. Thank you for the helpful suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was a case of having the same SPROC in two databases and not knowing it: code was hitting one database and I was testing my query in a different one.

Sorry for the stupid question and thank you all for the great answers.

Comment: I've been there before :)

Comment: Good that you found out :)